# Trying to make a custom table

Tags: css, html, tabular

I'm trying to make a table that looks like this:

[image]

But I'm not quite sure how to go about doing that.

The end result is supposed to look like this:

[image]

I was planning on having making a div, and then setting the background of the div to be the grey textured part, and then creating a table inside that div to organize the content. Is using a table in this situation correct? Or is there a better method? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The better method would be to just use divs for each section. I'm working on a jsFiddle to show you the concept.

Comment: and then just float them left and right within the container div?

Comment: You might wanna look at bootstrap scaffolding components, or you can set a fixed width for each row's div. But anyway, why won't you use table?

Comment: Im not against using a table, I just wasnt sure if there was a better way to do it. And Im also having trouble getting the table to line up that when I try to code it.

Comment: +1 for posing a clear question!

Comment: @vadz - it is not semantically correct to use tables unless you are displaying tabular data.  Further, maintenance becomes more difficult, and the styling available to a table is less flexible than for other elements.

Comment: @cale_b - i hvae no idea what tabular data is.. lol.. anyway, ure right about maintenancing part, since i experienced that.. nice lesson for me.. +1

Comment: @vadz - great question!  Tabular data is something like what you would see when you look at a spreadsheet.  It's columns / rows of data being presented.

Answer (score 6):

Stick to a non-table markup.  Best practices today would suggest you should only use tables for tabular data, and this content is not tabular data.

There's several different methods you could use to get this going, including using floats, displaying inline-block, and others.  There's also considerations with the content wrapping around the images (if the content is long, for example).

But here's some sample code to get your rolling.

Styles:

```
div.left,
div.right {
    width: 400px;
    overflow: hidden; /* forces the div to clear the floated content */
}

div.left img,
div.right img {
    border: 2px solid #888;
}

div.left img {
    float: left;
    padding-right: 20px;
}

div.right img {
    float: right;
    padding-left: 20px;
}
```

The html markup:

```
<div class="left">
    <img src="your_image_source"><p>Lorem Ipsump dolor sit amet</p>
</div>
<div class="right">
    <img src="your_image_source"><p>Lorem Ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice less markup.. = less bytes..

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/wJBCQ/)

This should show you exactly what you need.

```
<body>
    <div id="topLeft"></div>
    <div id="topRight"></div>
    <div id="middleLeft"></div>
    <div id="middleRight"></div>
    <div id="bottomLeft"></div>
    <div id="bottomRight"right></div>
</body>

body { 
    height:400px;
}
#topLeft {
    background-color:#000000;
    width:32%;
    height:32%;
    margin:5px;
    float:left;
}
#topRight {
    float:right;
    background-color: #000000;
    width:65%;
    height:32%;
    margin:5px;
}
#middleLeft {
    background-color:#000000;
    width:65%;
    height:32%;
    margin:5px;
    float:left;
}
#middleRight {
    float:right;
    background-color: #000000;
    width:32%;
    height:32%;
    margin:5px;
}
#bottomLeft {
    float:left;
    background-color: #000000;
    width:32%;
    height:32%;
    margin:5px;
}
#bottomRight {
    float:right;
    background-color: #000000;
    width:65%;
    height:32%;
    margin:5px;
}
```

The body can be replaced with a wrapper and sized appropriately.

```
Code on jsFiddle
```

Answer (score 0):

Fooey on those haters who say don't use tables. I would totally use a table for this.

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td colspan=1><img src="yadayada"></td>
    <td colspan=2>Lorem Ipsum...</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan=2>Lorem Ipsum...</td>
    <td colspan=1><img src="yadayada"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan=1><img src="yadayada"></td>
    <td colspan=2>Lorem Ipsum...</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This doesn't always work: browsers can get confused about calculating column widths if said columns never appear un-merged. It's vastly preferable to use one of the floaty options for what the OP wants.

Comment: Not hating, just have been down the road of using tables for layout, and paid the price.  This sample has more markup, and is less adjustable than a non-table layout.  With non-table solution, a quick flick of the css can make changes that are not possible with a table solution.